# Problem with referring to a paragraph

Tags: cross-referencing, paragraphs, appendices, ieeetran

I have paragraphs in my Appendix, which I have labeled them like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draftclsnofoot,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
  See Appendix~\ref{p.1}
  See Appendix~\ref{p.2}
\appendix

\paragraph{par1}\label{p.1}

Content of paragraph 1

\paragraph{par2}\label{p.2}

Content of paragraph 2
\end{document}
```

I have also used the packages  `mathtools`, `ifpdf`,  `amsthm` ,`amsmath`, `cite`, `amsfonts`, `url`, `amssymb`, `inputenc`, `lipsum`, and `hyperref`.

The output is

> See Appendix 0.a
>
> See Appendix 1.b
>
> Appendix
>
> a.par1
>
> Content of paragraph 1
>
> b.par2
>
> Content of paragraph 2

How can I get?:

> See Appendix A
>
> See Appendix B
>
> Appendix
>
> A.par1
>
> Content of paragraph 1
>
> B.par2
>
> Content of paragraph 2

One way is to use `\subsection` instead of `\paragraph`, but it is a waste of space and I have a space limit, since using `\subsection` makes you write the content of that subsection from the line after the title line. However, when you use `\paragraph`, you can write the content of the paragraph on the title line. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks. How does it look now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend this because it might be rejected by `IEEETran` editors etc.

The `\theparagraph` macro has multiple definitions, depending on class options, but the easiest way is to use `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}}` after `\appendix.

However, the number in the paragraph header is set with `\@seccntformat` which uses `\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 0.5em\relax}` where `\theparagraphdis` is defined somewhere in the `.cls` file, having different meanings depending (again) on the class options.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draftclsnofoot,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}


\begin{document}

  See Appendix~\ref{p.1}

  See Appendix~\ref{p.2}

\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}}% Redefine the output of the `paragraph` counter to use upper case (\Alph)` letters
 % Redefine `\@seccntformat` to use `\the...` and not `\the...dis`. 
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
%Alternatively use 
%\let\theparagraphdis\theparagraph
\makeatother


\paragraph{Paragraph one}\label{p.1}

Content of paragraph 1

\paragraph{Paragraph two}\label{p.2}

Content of paragraph 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works. Can you clarify the meaning of each of the lines by comments?

Comment: @Sus20200: Done so -- is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes, thanks. If you don't recommend this, what is your recommendation?

Comment: @Sus20200: If you plan to submit your article to IEEETran they might reject the changes of numbering style etc, that's why I don't recommend it.